# Java regex for matching curly braces and brackets within braces

Tags: java, regex

I have the following String - `There are {num} scores {/game/[game_name]/game_in}`.
I want to extract `num` and `game_name` from the string.
I have the following Pattern - `"\\{([^}]+)}"` which extract `num` from the String. How can I extend it to extract `game_name` also?

Comment: Make two separate regular expressions. That is way simpler and more logical.

Comment: I want to extract them as part of the single call as I'll have many such string and don't want to work on multiple matches.

Comment: @anubhava This regex isn't compiling in Java.. Trying to make it work.

Comment: In Java use: `String regex = "\\{([^\\]\\[\\{\\}]+)\\}.*?\\[([^\\]\\[\\{\\}]+)]";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you can use this regex and code:

```
String s = "{num} scores {/game/[game_name]/game_in}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
                 "\\{([^]\\[\\{\\}]+)\\}.*?\\[([^]\\[\\{\\}]+)]");

List<String> res = p.matcher(s)
   .results()
   .flatMap(mr -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, mr.groupCount())
   .mapToObj(mr::group))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
//=> [num, game_name]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q19EBE/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\{`: Match `{`
- `([^]\[{}]+)`: Capture group #1 to capture 1+ of any char that is not `{, }, [, ]`
- `}`: Match `}`
- `.*?`: Match any text (lazy)
- `\[`: Match `[`
- `([^]\[{}]+)`: Capture group #2 to capture 1+ of any char that is not `{, }, [, ]`
- `]`: Match `]`

Comment: This does work! However, I realized I didn't frame my question correctly. The String could be `There are {num} scores {/game/[game_name]/game_in}` or `There are num scores {/game/[game_name]/game_in}` or `There are {num} scores in football`. The answer works only for the first case. It would be great if you could improve upon it, if not then I'll anyways accept your answer for all your help.

Comment: See your question was about matching string inside the curly braces and brackets. If there are no curly braces then which string should be matched in `There are num scores {/game/[game_name]/game_in}`?

Comment: Then I would expect to return `game_name`.

Comment: For those cases check this demo: https://regex101.com/r/q19EBE/2